# Program.service ExecStart fails but the program itself runs

Tags: service, centos7

I am testing how to run a script using a .service file on CentOS7.

The script is a very simple loop just to make sure it runs:

```
if [ "$1" == "start" ] || [ "$1" == "cycle" ]
then
    /u/Test/Bincustom/haltrun_wrap.sh run &
    echo $!  /u/Test/Locks/start.pid
    exit
elif [ "$1" == "stop" ] || [ "$1" == "halt" ]
then
    killall -q -9 haltrun_wrap.sh
    echo " "  /u/Test/Locks/start.pid
elif [ "$1" == "run" ]
then
    process_id=$(pidof haltrun_wrap.sh)
    #echo $process_id  /u/Test/Locks/start.pid
    while [ 1 ]
    do
        CurTime=$(date)
        echo $CurTime  /u/Test/Logs/log
        sleep 30s
    done
else
    cat /u/Test/Locks/start.pid
    cat /u/Test/Logs/log
fi
```

That script runs fine as the root or test user if i launch manually.

The Program.service file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Program

[Service]
Type=forking
RemainAfterExit=yes
PIDFile=/u/Test/Locks/start.pid
EnvironmentFile=/u/Test/Config/environ
Environment="Base="sudo -u sirsi '/u/Test/Bincustom/Program " "Stop=halt force'" "Start=cycle force'""
ExecStart=/bin/sh $Base$Start
ExecStop=/bin/sh $Base$Stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
WantedBy=WebServices
WantedBy=BCA
```

The error is always:

```
● Program.service - Program
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/Program.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: resources) since Wed 2017-01-11 14:53:10 MST; 1s ago
  Process: 12014 ExecStart=/bin/sh $Base$Start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jan 11 14:53:09 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Program...
Jan 11 14:53:10 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: PID file /u/Test/Locks/start.pid not readable (yet?) after start.
Jan 11 14:53:10 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Program.
Jan 11 14:53:10 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit Program.service entered failed state.
Jan 11 14:53:10 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Program.service failed.
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong in the .service but for the life of me I am still missing it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the line:

> Environment="Base="sudo -u sirsi '/u/Test/Bincustom/Program " "Stop=halt force'" "Start=cycle force'""
>   ExecStart=/bin/sh $Base$Start 
>   ExecStop=/bin/sh $Base$Stop

Apparently .service files do not recognize variables.

I also had an issue with sudo not being allowed to run my test script.
i had to add the sudo into the test script.